# How to detect changes URL with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How can jQuery detect changes to a url?

For example: 
If a user goes to a page site.com/info nothing shows, but if he goes to site.com/info?more jquery detects it and does something.

Thanks

Comment: 0_0...... what?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Hi :) What you dont understand? How to detect URL changes with jQuery?

Comment: @MrCheezezs: I don't understand your example

Comment: @ClaudioRedi if a user goes to a page with url "site.com/info" nothing shows, but if he goes to url "site.com/info?more" jquery detects it and does something. sign "?more" its like "#more"

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Please see the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of url queries should always be managed to the server side, but it is possible for javascript and jQuery to handle `window.location.hash` for the hash `#` arguments and `window.location.search` for the `?` argument.

**A simple axample of parsing the `window.location.search` string:**

```
var search_data = window.location.search;
var params = search_data .substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to remove the ?

for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
    var p = params[i].split('=');
    console.log('Arg name: ', p[0], 'Arg value: ', p[1]);
}
```